# Finding a prime number between $n$ and $2n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to find a prime number between $n$ and $2n$.

I know that the number of primes between $n$ and $2n$ is $n/(2\ln n)$.

I was thinking of choosing a random number between $n$ and $2n$ and check if its prime. If no, repeat.

However, how do I find the repetitions needed to make sure I find a prime with a probability of .99?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your second assertion is incorrect. The number of primes between $n$ and $2n$ is a natural number but $n/(2\ln n)$ is usually not a natural number. So what you say can't be right.

Comment: It is an approximation.

Comment: that is not what you wrote in the question. You need to be precise.

Comment: Hello Andrew, welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  It would help us to answer it if you provide more context (where the problem comes from) together with what you've tried so far.  You should consider [editing](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/377705/edit) your post to include more details, and try to be more precise as the other commenters have suggested.

Comment: @Andrew : I am pretty sure that, surprisingly, this naive procedure is similar to what people actually do when they are trying to find large prime numbers.  Are there any cryptography experts out there who can back me up?

Comment: @StefanSmith: I'm not in crypto, but I can verify that this is the way it's usually done, with a few modifications as needed.

Comment: I am in crypto, and this is how I do it on my laptop. In my chip card I have to be a bit smarter, storing residues modulo a list of small primes and generating prime candidates using a scrambled pseudo-random walk that lets me update these residues quickly. So I can rule out most candidates immediately. But the principle is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your estimate for the number of primes is wrong: there are about
$$\frac{n}{\log n}$$
primes between $n$ and $2n$. More specifically, the number is
$$n/\log n-kn/\log^2n+O(n/\log^3n)$$
where $k=\log4-1=0.386\ldots.$

That aside, you're essentially being asked to use the geometric distribution here. If your chance of failure is
$$
1-\frac{1}{\log n}
$$
then your chance of failure after $k$ trials is
$$
(1-\frac{1}{\log n})^k
$$
and you can solve
$$
(1-\frac{1}{\log n})^k=0.01
$$
by taking logarithms.

As a practical matter you might exclude even numbers from your search. In that case your chance of success per trial doubles and you can solve
$$
(1-\frac{2}{\log n})^k=0.01
$$
instead.

Comment: I'm sceptical about your final result as for $n=1000$, $(1-\frac{2}{\log n})^k=0.99$ yields $k\approx0.0294$. You're right about the even search optimization though.

Comment: @Maazul: 1000 is pretty small. Let's take $n=10^{100}$ and test 100,000 random odd numbers $n$ to $2n$. I find 822 primes, or 0.00822 primes per odd. The prediction is $2/\log(10^{100})\approx0.00868.$ Looks pretty close to me. As for the $k$ part, you're right; I should be solving for 0.01 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is known as the [Bertrand postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate):

> For every $n > 1$ there is always at least one prime $p$ such that $n < p < 2n$.

Proving the conjecture isn't trivial, you can find a [proof by Erdős](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) on Wikipedia. He proved even [stronger result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_postulate#Erd.C5.91s.27s_theorems) that

> ... for any positive integer $k$, there is a natural number $N$ such that for all $n > N$, there are at least $k$ primes between $n$ and $2n$.

Comment: Isn't the question programming-oriented?

Comment: @Maazul Well it's in math section and with tag _number theory_ so I hope my answer is still relevant. Even if it were purely programming question, I believe that knowing if it has a solution at all is very important.

Answer (score 1):

By the Prime Number Theorem, ${\pi(2n)}-{\pi(n)} \approx \frac{2n}{\ln(2n)}-\frac{n}{\ln(n)} \approx \frac{n}{2\ln(n)}$. Now that is quite an approximation. But supposing we play by your rules, the probability that we will encounter a prime if we randomly picked a number between $n$ and $2n$ is $\frac{1}{2\ln(n)}$. We say that we run $r$ such trials or repititions such that the probability that there will be at least one prime in the search is $0.99$. Employing binomial distribution we get

$$\begin{align} 1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2\ln(n)} \right)^{r} &= 0.99 \\ 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2\ln(n)} \right)^{r} &= 0.01. \end{align}$$

Solving for $r$ yields

$$ r=\log_{\left(1-\frac{1}{2\ln(n)}\right)}0.01=\frac{\ln(0.01)}{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2\ln(n)}\right)}.$$

The number of trials or repititions required such that the probability that we will encounter a prime at least once between $n$ and $2n$ is $\left\lceil \ln(0.01)/\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2\ln(n)}\right)\right\rceil$.

Comment: "Now that is quite an approximation." - It is quite close for reasonably large $n$, so it's not that bad.

Comment: This approximation actually contradicts the Prime Number Theorem, see my answer.